# Clearing all catalog_product_flat tables in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, ssh

I am a begginer with magento. I was having a problem reindexing my product flat data and I was suggested the following:
1. Backup your database

1. Switch off the Use Flat Product and Category options in Magento and switch the Index mode from the Product Flat Data to Manual update.
2. Go into your DB, clear all catalog_product_flat tables:

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
   TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_1;
   TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_2; 
   ...
   TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_flat_{N};
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
3. Reindex the catalog via SSH:

php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat

1. When it’s done you can activate the use Flat products option.

I do not understand how to perform step 3. I do have ssh access into the server but I don't understand how to run the sql commands.

Comment: on step three you should be into your Magento_Root directory. Inside it you have the folder shell and then the file indexer.php. Once you run the command below it should recreate the indexes for that particular section, in your case catalog_product_flat .

Comment: Thanks for the help. Anyways I found a tool called n98-magerun which makes the process of performing sql queires really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 3 isn't a SQL command, it's a shell command.

Running it is pretty simple:

1. SSH into the server
2. `cd` to your Magento root folder (where your index.php resides)
3. run the provided command: `php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat`

What's happening is that you're telling the `php` program to run the `shell/indexer.php` script, and passing it the additional parameter of `--reindex catalog_product_flat`